# IBM MQ client jars disable FFST stack trace

Tags: java, tomcat7, ibm-mq

I have an app written in java 7 deployed into Tomcat 7 application server running on CentOS7.

In the java app I am using following jars to connect to IBM MQ message broker.

```
`connector-7.0.1.11.jar`
`dhbcore-7.0.1.11.jar`
`mq-7.0.1.11.jar`
`mq-jmqi-7.0.1.11.jar`
`mqjms-7.0.1.11.jar`
```

Sometimes when my application fails to open a connection with MQ, it starts filling catalina.out with FFST calls. These logs traces are very very verbose and filling the disk with in minutes and leading to server crash.

I tried following system options to turn off these traces but didn't work.

```
`Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.ffst.suppress=-1`
`Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.status=OFF` 
`Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=OFF` 
`Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.maxBytes=0`
```

How can I turn off these? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add a logrotate based on filesize and max number of files so that tomcat get rid of the thrash

Comment: The following option does not turn off FFST, `-Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.ffst.suppress=-1` is documented as "causes only the first FFDC of a particular type to be output".  You are using jar files from a version of MQ that has been out of support since September 2015.